# How does density value calculate in android

Tags: android

Can anybody explain me what formula android use to calculate screen density?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Density can be calculated by the following formula:

```
Density = sqrt((wp * wp) + (hp * hp)) / di
```

Where:

`wp` is width resolution in pixels,

`hp` is height resolution in pixels, and

`di` is diagonal size in inches.

Comment: This formula actully for [ppi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) but android likes the term `dpi` instead. Difference can be read [here](http://www.andrewdaceyphotography.com/articles/dpi/)

Comment: what is diagonal size in inches?

Comment: the distance between two opposite edges of a phone is called diagonal size.

Comment: Don't forget to divide bij 160 afterwards

Answer (score 6):

The formula is actual-dpi / 160. (Everything is scaled to 160 dpi.)

Comment: Thanks for respond, Ted. But what is actual value?

Comment: @teoREtik - Sorry I wasn't clear. There is no value "actual" and what I posted wasn't a formula involving subtraction. The `actual-dpi` is the value of the screen's actual dots-per-inch.

Answer (score 1):

```
int pixel = 120;
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dip = (int) (pixel* scale + 0.5f);
```

Refer this following links

- [getDisplayMetrics()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDisplayMetrics%28%29), for current display metrics
- [density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density), This is a scaling factor for the Density Independent Pixel unit

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have to repeat my question again. I want to know how does OS Android calculate density. In your code snippet it is scale value.

Comment: I read a documentation about density, but I didn`t understand it completely. So I want to know, how does it calculate. That`s why I established this question

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. Explain a little more what you want to accomplish. Android's concept of density is the ratio of actual number of pixels/inch to the default pixel density of 160 pixels per inch. Take a look at the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class docs.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate screen density, you can use this equation:

> **Screen density** = Screen width (or height) in pixels / Screen width (or height) in inches